# Segmentation fault while sorting large array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to sort an array whose elements are read from a file which is approximately 5 GB in size and contains approximately 500000 data elements.

After a data size of 300.000.000, the program gives an error during sorting due to segmentation fault and terminates.

I think the problem occurs due to insufficient memory space allocated to program. How can I change it in my C code?

Could you help me about this? Thank you.

```
int arraysize = atoi(argv[1]);
int* array    = malloc(sizeof(int)*arraysize);
int* temp     = malloc(sizeof(int)*arraysize);
int i;

FILE *fi;
char buffer[20];
fi = fopen("DATASET.dat", "r");

for(i=0; i<arraysize; i++){
  fgets(buffer, 20, fi);
  array[i] = atoi(buffer);
}

fclose(fi);

//function is called to perform the sorting
mergesort_array(array, arraysize, temp);
```

Comment: You need to provide more info: how you allocate the array, how you read the data into it, how large are the data elements, and whether the code segfaults while reading the data or during the actual sort.

Comment: Needs code. All modern systems use virtual memory, so you should be able to use many gigabytes of memory (even more than your computer has installed, since it will start swapping to disk) before your program crashes due to lack of memory.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry so long as "many" means no more than four(4) in a 32-bit virtual address space (i.e. compiling 32bit rather than 64bit code), I suppose this is true. If the OP is compiling 32bit code the most memory he can address, virtual or otherwise, is 4gB. That, of course, goes out the door with a 64bit process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int* array    = malloc(sizeof(int)*arraysize);
>   int* temp     = malloc(sizeof(int)*arraysize);

In general, whenever you allocate memory, check that the allocation succeeded:

```
int *array = NULL, *temp = NULL;

if (NULL == (array = malloc(sizeof(int)*arraysize)))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory allocating %d bytes\n", sizeof(int)*arraysize);
    abort();
}
if (NULL == (temp = malloc(sizeof(int)*arraysize)))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory allocating %d bytes\n", sizeof(int)*arraysize);
    abort();
}
```

Then, a possibility would be to implement mergesorting *on disk*, using a file of integers (you can mmap() the file, too).

But I find it strange that an allocation of 300000 integers on the heap - 4.8 megabytes at the most, using 64-bit integers - can cause an allocation error, so I think this is something in the mergesort implementation; maybe something having to do with a recursive implementation.

I'd start with compiling the program with full debug information, and checking the core dump with `gdb`.

### A "simple" malloc problem

Having to handle a very large array of *ASCII strings representing numbers*, you could start by first converting it to a file of *integers*.

```
FILE *fi, *fo, *ft;
char buffer[20];
int  array[4096], b = 0;

fi = fopen("DATASET.dat", "r");
if (NULL == fi)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file\n");
    abort();
}
fo = fopen("INTEGER.dat", "w");
if (NULL == fo)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open output file\n");
    abort();
}
ft = fopen("TEMP.dat", "w");
if (NULL == ft)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open output file\n");
    abort();
}
for(i=0; i<arraysize; i++){
   fgets(buffer, 20, fi);
   array[b++] = atoi(buffer);
   if (4096 == b)
   {
       if (b != fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), b, fo))
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "write error\n");
           abort();
       }
       if (b != fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), b, ft))
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "write error\n");
           abort();
       }
       b = 0;
   }
}
if (b)
{
    if (b != fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), b, fo))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write error\n");
        abort();
    }
    if (b != fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), b, ft))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write error\n");
        abort();
    }
}
fclose(fi); fi = NULL;
fclose(fo); fo = NULL;
fclose(ft); ft = NULL;
```

Now you have an `INTEGER.dat` file which is made of integers of fixed size. It is, to all intents and purposes, a file copy of an array in memory. Same goes for the temporary array.

And you *can* tell the system to treat that file as if it was an array in memory.

```
int *sort = NULL;
int *temp = NULL;

// Temp is not shown -- identical treatment as sort

fd = open ("INTEGERS.dat", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot reopen output\n");
    abort();
}
if (MAP_FAILED == (sort = mmap (0, arraysize*sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap error\n");
    abort();
}
if (-1 == close (fd))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error closing output file\n");
    return 1;
}

do_sort(sort, temp, arraysize);

if (-1 == munmap (sort, arraysize*sizeof(int)))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error releasing mmap for %s\n", "sort");
    abort();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I mistyped the value of the number. It should be 300 million.

Comment: I also applied your suggestion. It gives an error while trying to sort 400 million elements:                                               Out of memory allocating 1600000000 bytes.

Comment: Hmmm. Then you might be asking for 1.2, 2.4 or 4.8 *giga* bytes of memory... it might be too much. Is this a homework of some sort? That is, do you *have* to do it that way, and is that humongous array the professor's way of telling you to *really* implement it as a file-based (or **mmap**) sort instead of using a RAM shortcut? (if it were *my* professor, it would be :-) ).

Comment: Thank you. Actually it should be a file-based sort.

Comment: Oh-hum. Then probably the mmap() version isn't acceptable. You ought instead to create two files for each iteration. Maybe, you can still use the same concept by positioning yourself over the INTEGERS "file-array" using `fseek`, reading two chunks of integers, and merging them onto TEMP. With chunks of some hundred megabytes, work should be pretty fast while still being conceptually file-based.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried to apply mmap to my code as shown above. However, execution terminates with a "Bus error".

Comment: I'll check the implementation later tonight.

Comment: Thanks again. I use gcc to compile my code on an Ubuntu OS. Is it possible that gcc assigns a default stack size to my program so a memory overflow occurs? If so, would it be possible to change this parameter while compiling?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using 32 bit operating system version, or at least 32 bit compiler, resulting ib 32 bit pointers, and max 4 gigs of memory (or even less, depending on OS). Switch to 64 bit OS and compile with 64 bit compiler.

Problem with 32 bit OS is, it simply cannot address enough memory for your "naive" algorithm, which requires all data to be in one flat memory space. Using mmap would not help either, for same reason. If you have to stick with 32 bit mode, you have to merge sort in parts, using files.

Comment: +1 it is highly likely this will ultimately be the reason he's hosed on his 10gB memory request. Even using an in-place sort like qsort() will still require more than 1gB of space he can't have as a 32bit process. Finally, the suggestion that without going to 64bit he'll need to partition-sort using files is *spot-on*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would use a database if your data set is this large. You can then get this for free along with easy methods to access/insert/update/delete data.

However to answer your question and you have problems allocating memory try using memory mapped files instead. See [mmap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) if on Linux or UNIX.